# Fuslogvw.exe tool for .Net does not show UI

Tags: .net, fuslogvw

I'm trying to use fuslogvw.exe on a Win 2008 R2 system.  It shows the process started and using CPU but no UI appears.  I've tried the 32bit and 64bit version in and not in admin mode but no luck.  I don't see anything in the event log as a problem.

Comment: @unforgiven3, apart from the fact that the Assembly Binding Log Viewer "helps you diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot locate an assembly at run time", I've used it before when trying to work out why a plugin wasn't loading in a product I work on. It's *very* much programming related.

Comment: @Rob, even if the question was "Visual Studio 2008 won't run on my PC", I still would have voted to close it. Sorry, but I don't equate general troubleshooting with programming.

Comment: @Rob, there are other sites in the StackOverflow trilogy that would be better suited for general troubleshooting.

Comment: @unforgiven3 Name one. Instead of just voting to close, suppose we actually be helpful and direct the person to a better place?  (for the record, I don't think there is one)

Answer (score 24):

If you cannot get the UI to work, it is not actually needed to configure and view the fusion logs. You can set the fusion log settings in the registry under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Fusion` key, and then view the logs directly from the directory you have configured (as they are just HTML files).

If you want to configure the logs using the registry, you need to set the following keys (from [here](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=12)):

- **LogFailures = 1** (DWORD Value)
  This turns on failure logging so that failed attempts to locate all assemblies are logged.
- **LogResourceBinds = 1** (DWORD Value)
  This turns on failure logging so that failed attempts to locate satellite assemblies are logged. This is not logged by default.
- **ForceLog = 1** (DWORD Value)
  This turns on logging for all assembly binds - both failures and successes. By default, only failures are logged. This is useful if you want to verify that an assembly is loading from a specific directory instead of from the global assembly cache.
- **LogPath = "C:\fusionlogs\"** (String Value)
  If you want to view the fusion logs easily, set the LogPath to a directory to output them to. By default the log files go into the Temporary Internet Files folder of the current user’s profile. For an ASP.Net or a .Net Windows service application, the only way to view the fusion log is to use this option. This is because they run as users other than the current user. The directory specified must already exist and have appropriate file permissions to be written to. For ASP.Net applications, the ASPNET user must have write permission to the directory. If the permissions are wrong, there will be no log output.

Comment: +1. This is one of the most helpful posts I've read. Hunting down FUSLOGVW and getting it on to production machines is the bane of my life, and now I don't have to :) Thank you!

Comment: Most useful answer on SO and perhaps the whole internet. A1+++ would use to solve binging issues again

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the exact same issue. `fuslogvw.exe` would start but seemingly freeze on startup.

As it turns out, I had forgotten to turn off logging last time I was checking binding logs. So I now had in the range of 40000 folders in Default and a similar amount in Native (and hundreds of thousands of log files). I can only assume that the log viewer was trying to load all of these up as it was starting and that's what stopped it in its tracks.

Deleted the logs and the log viewer starts up as expected.

Comment: I guess folks don't want to 'fess up their mistakes... I'll admit, this was the cause of my problem. Great answer!!